# template class specialization : template-id does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to use templates, but couldn't understand what is wrong with below code.

**solve.h**

```
#include "nlp.h"
#include "Ipopt_solve.h"

enum algo_type {IPOPT =1, SQP};

template<int ALG>
class solve
{
public:
    solve()
    {
    }
};

template<>
class solve<IPOPT>
{
public:
    solve(nlp*);

private:
    Ipopt_solve m_ipopt;

};
```

**solve.cpp**

```
template<>
solve<IPOPT>::solve(nlp* problem): m_ipopt(problem)
{
}
```

`Ipopt_solve` is a sub-class of an abstract class `TNLP`. `Ipopt_solve` is initialized with a reference to `nlp` class.

**from main.cpp**

```
nlp problem(&model);
solve<IPOPT> solution(&problem);
```

I'm getting the error like shown below.

**error: template-id 'solve<>' for 'solve<1>::solve(nlp*)' does not match any template declaration
 solve::solve(nlp* problem): m_ipopt(problem)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `template<>`, i.e.

```
// template <>
solve<IPOPT>::solve(nlp* problem): m_ipopt(problem)
{
}
```

`template<>` is used for template specialization (for a template); but you're just defining a non-template member function (of a class template specialization). (That's why the compiler complains that the template declaration can't be found.)

Answer (score 5):

This declaration in its original form

```
template<>
solve<IPOPT>::solve(nlp* problem): m_ipopt(problem)
{
}
```

is formally valid by itself. However, it is not doing what you think it is doing. This declaration declares an explicit specialization for a member *of the main template*

```
template<int ALG>
class solve
{
  ...
```

It has no relation to your explicit specialization

```
template<>
class solve<IPOPT>
{
  ...
```

The compiler is trying to specialize constructor `solve<ALG>::solve(nlp* problem)` *of the main template*. However, the main template has no such constructor. Hence the error message, that tells you exactly that: the compiler does not understand what constructor you are trying to specialize, it cannot find the matching member in the main template.

For example, you can use this syntax to explicitly specialize the default constructor of the main template

```
template<>
solve<SQP>::solve()
{
  // Specialized code for `solve<SQP>`'s default constructor
}
```

This will compile fine since the main template does indeed have such constructor. (Note that you don't have to explicitly specialize the whole class for that, you can just explicitly specialize the constructor.)

Your intent was, obviously, completely different: to provide definition for the constructor in the class template specialization

```
template<>
class solve<IPOPT>
{
  ...
```

The proper syntax for that should not mention `template<>`

```
solve<IPOPT>::solve(nlp* problem): m_ipopt(problem)
{
}
```